# scala get the basedirectory path in build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

i need to add the base directory path to system property

```
lazy val bas = baseDirectory.value.getPath
initialize ~= { _ =>
  System.setProperty( "report.path",  bas+"/reports/l2report")
  System.setProperty( "build-version", buildVersion)
}



build.sbt:111: error: `value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.
```

this error is coming build.sbt

Comment: Is it sbt 0.13?

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is. `baseDirectory.value` might have different values in different scopes, so you can't access it from the top level like that.